# Oracle for NP complete problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

What if we had an oracle for solving all NP problems which has exactly one solution in polynomial time.

The oracle fails if the NP problem has more than 1 solution.
The question is can we use this oracle to solve all NP problems in polynomial time even if they have multiple solutions?

Comment: IIUC, you are asking if $NP \subseteq P^{UP}$. See the [UP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UP_(complexity)).

Comment: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos528/handouts/NP_is_as.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valiant%E2%80%93Vazirani_theorem

Comment: Depending on what exactly "the oracle fails" means, the question may rather be if $\mathrm{NP}\subseteq\mathrm{P^{promiseUP}}$.